# Bootstrap 4 Grid mosaic

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I had built a small mosaic with Bootstrap 3 as follows : [Working mosaic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3bXg.png).
I now have a site under bootstrap 4 and when I want to reuse my mosaic I get this: [Broken mosaic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4sH1.png).

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 B"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 O"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css

```
.row > div {border:10px solid white}
.B {background:blue; height:200px}
.G {background:green; height:100px}
.O {background:orange; height:100px}
```

Does anyone know what happened between version 3 and 4? Do you have a fix without using js?

Tank's a million!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to override Bootstrap 4 flexbox using the included display and float utils..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-block">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 float-left B"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 float-left O"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/gAaNjAHjVh